# Access jackrabbit repository through Apache Sling

Tags: jackrabbit, sling

I followed Apache Sling [tutorials](http://sling.apache.org/site/discover-sling-in-15-minutes.html) using its [Launchpad](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/sling/org.apache.sling.launchpad-6-standalone.jar). As I understood, it uses a built in jackrabbit repository within the Launchpad. 
Is there a way to access a standalone jackrabbit repository using Sling API without using its launchpad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The embedded repository is provided by the org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.server bundle, so if this bundle and the ones that it requires are active you should get the corresponding SlingRepository service, backed by an embedded Jackrabbit repository.

Comment: I configured external repo details through ConfigAdmin according to following post. http://apache-sling.73963.n3.nabble.com/configuring-jackrabbit-td880359.html#a881063 
But now, when I try to access http://localhost:8080/content, I get 503 error saying "AuthenticationSupport service missing. Cannot authenticate request.". Can you please tell me what I have missed? Thank you.